# Modify body of a http Result in PlayFramework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using version 2.0.2 of the [PlayFramework](http://www.playframework.org/), and am trying to create a play `play.mvc.Action` to implement a **post filter** for http Results.

Examples of using actors for pre-processing are explained in the [play docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaActionsComposition).

However what I want to achieve is a little different. I need to:

- Take a `play.mvc.Result`
- **Extract the body**
- Apply a transform to the body
- Then create a new Result.

The `Result` interface **does not expose the http body**, and even assuming you had the specific subclass (say `SimpleResult`, or `AsyncResult`) I am not sure how to extract the message body.

My specific use case is a filter to GZip the result body and add the correct 'Content-Encoding' header. I want to be able to apply this `GZip` filter to any existing Controller by adding an annotation similarly to how authentication is implemented in the docs.

Below is an example of what I am trying to do

```
public class Compress {
  @With(GZipResult.class)
  public @interface GZip {
  }

  public static class GZipResult extends Action<GZip> {
    @Override
    public Result call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
      Result result = delegate.call(ctx);
      if (requestSupportsGZip(ctx) {
         result = extractAndGZipResult(result); //how to extract http body?
      }
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

which can be used as

```
@Compress.GZip
class MyController extends Controller {
   public static Result index() {
      return ok(someHtml);
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. By reading your explanation, you seem to want to gzip the body of your response to the clients, but by looking to your code, you are trying to Gzip the request. What you exactly mean by "result"; in Play, a Result is a response, but in your code, it's a Request (`Request result = delegate.call(ctx);`)

Comment: @nico: That was a typo on my behalf. `s/Request/Result/g`

Answer (score 4):

I got a similar case in modifying the http result. I would like to share my approach in dealing with this in Java.

Upon examining the Scala source code of Play 2.0.3, I found that `play.core.j.JavaResultExtractor` can retrieve the response body, cookies, headers, and status of the `Result` class in Java and `play.core.j.JavaResults` can write the content of response body.

Despite of that, I still don't know how to replace the current response body with the modified body in a easy way. Maybe dealing this with Scala implementation would be easier but I still found Scala too arcane to read :-(

The way that I found is to see how `play.mvc.Results.Status` is implemented, which uses the `play.core.j.JavaResults` to write content body. The class that I mentioned is the heart of `ok()`, `notFound()`, `forbidden()`, and other similar methods in generating `Result` in `Controller` class in Java.  The implementation of this class looks like this: *(refactored the Scala classes for readability)*

```java
// scala classes
import play.api.mvc.Codec;
import play.api.mvc.Content;
import play.core.j.JavaResults;
// ...    

    public static class Status implements Result {
        final private play.api.mvc.Result wrappedResult;
        // ... 

        // there are a lot of constructors for this class to reference from
        // this particular constructor is the general approach for most cases
        public Status(play.api.mvc.Results.Status status, Content content, Codec codec) {
            // ...
            wrappedResult = status.apply(
                content,
                JavaResults.writeContent(codec),
                JavaResults.contentTypeOf(content.contentType() + "; charset=" + codec.charset())
            );
        }

}
```

If you wish to implement the code above, you also need to implement the `play.api.mvc.Content` interface. All in all, implementing your code from the things I said  would look like this:

```java
import play.api.mvc.Codec;
import play.api.mvc.Content;
import play.core.j.JavaResultExtractor;
import play.core.j.JavaResults;
// ...

public static class GZipResult extends Action<GZip> {

    @Override
    public Result call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        Result result = delegate.call(ctx);
        if (requestSupportsGZip(ctx)) {
            // copy parts of current response
            final int statusCode = JavaResultExtractor.getStatus(result);
            final Map<String,String> headers = JavaResultExtractor.getHeaders(result);
            final byte[] body = JavaResultExtractor.getBody(result);

            // create a gzip result
            result = new GZipResult(statusCode, new String(body), headers.get("Content-Type"));

            // add appropriate headers here
            // ...
        }

        return result;
    }
}

private static class GZipResult implements Result {
    final private play.api.mvc.Result wrappedResult;

    public GZipResult(final int StatusCode, final String content, final String contentType) {
        if(content == null) throw new NullPointerException("null content");

        // i guess this is the good place in transforming the content body
        String gzippedContent = someMethodToGzipContent(content);

        this.wrappedResult = JavaResults.Status(statusCode).apply(
                // implement the play.api.mvc.Content interface
                new Content() {
                    @Override public String body() { return gzippedContent; }
                    @Override public String contentType() { return contentType; }
                },
                JavaResults.writeContent(Codec.utf_8),
                JavaResults.contentTypeOf(contentType))
            );
    }

    // ...
}
```

With the implementation above, I can modify the http result. I hope this can help you for your particular use case.

Cheers!

### Update

The code above can solve most use-cases in modifying the http result. Your particular case, that is gzipping response, requires an alternate approach since a gzipped body is in `byte[]` not in `String`. The `play.mvc.Results.Status` class also provide method in handling `byte[]`. The implementation looks like this:

```java
// scala classes
import play.core.j.JavaResults;
// ...    

    public static class Status implements Result {
        final private play.api.mvc.Result wrappedResult;
        // ... 

        public Status(play.api.mvc.Results.Status status, byte[] content) {
            // ...
            wrappedResult = status.apply(
                content,
                JavaResults.writeBytes(),
                JavaResults.contentTypeOfBytes()
            );
        }

}
```

You can figure out how to do this to your code basing from my implementation before my update. Note that you do not need to implement `play.api.mvc.Content` anymore and be sure to return an appropriate content-type on the response.

Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, after some digging, you can get the body of your response using `result.getWrappedResult()`; it returns a `play.api.mvc.Result` which can (generally) be cast to a `play.api.mvc.SimpleResult` which contains a `body()` method:

```
play.api.mvc.SimpleResult wrappedResult = (play.api.mvc.SimpleResult) result.getWrappedResult();
Enumerator body = wrappedResult.body();
```

Then, I suggest you to read the [Enumerator doc](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/Enumerators); for the moment, I haven't figured out myself how these things work :-).

Hope this helps you a little...